# Kibana / Elasticsearch not pulling data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to use Kibana and Elasticsearch to work with data logs.

I can see that Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash are running, but can not get Kibana to pull an analyze data from Logstash.

I´ve attached some screenshots below.

[No results found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0DL8.png)

[Configurations of Logstash in Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3Ef.png)

Comment: Try changing Time Range at the top-right corner from 15 minutes to for example Last 1 Year.

Comment: That helped, but it looks like it stopped pulling data about 1.5 hours ago.  Is there a way to fix that?  Is it most likely logstash related?

Comment: Show your Logstash config file and check if Logstash is still running on Linux `service logstash status`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the logstash file wasn´t running on Linux.  I used the `service logstash status` command and realized that it was stopped.

After starting the service, everything returned to normal.